# How change format date in SQL Server or how true insert datetime in SQL Server by c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have string `date="20130613070000+1000"` I convert to datatime by using:

```
date_dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

results its `date_dt=13/06/2013 12:00:00 AM`

I insert into database SQL Server using

```
insert into date (startdate) VALUES ('13/06/2013 12:00:00 PM')
```

I have a problem - I get an error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 6
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What's the solution for `dt_date` convert with fomat `MM/dd/yyy` ?

Comment: Do *not* insert values in the sql statement string in code! *Do* use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032495/insert-datetime-value-in-sql-database-with-c-sharp

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = "insert into date(startdate) values (@startDate)"; cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("startDate", date_dt);` - ***job done***

Answer (score 1):

How are you inserting in the database? From C# code you should always use parameters for passing values. The framework does the conversion for you!

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f844fc7.aspx

Comment: Didn't downvote but I think this doesn't answer the question. Even after your edit.

Comment: @SonerGönül on the contrary, I think it is **the** answer to this question. If you ever find yourself having to wonder how to parse or format dates (or any other type, for that matter), then it means you are *doing it wrong*. The **correct** thing to do here is to express that as a parameter, rather than as a literal

Comment: @SonerGönül the question is (also) "how to insert datetime by c#" there's no doubt that the standard way is via SqlParameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ISO 8601 format when inserting the date as a string. This should work across all cultures:

```
date_dt.ToString("s")
```

Example output:

```
2013-06-13T10:29:57
```

Alternatively, you can use a SqlCommand with parameters which will do the conversion for you.

Comment: not this i need to insert ino sql by datetime type but i need to equals betwen datetime format in sql and datetime format in asp.net or c#

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The output from SQL server is a DateTime instance. If your date value on the server also is a DateTime instance comparing them should be easy? You might have to convert to/from UTC if you support multiple timezones.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following convert function to convert your date string to SQL date time format

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME 
SET @MyDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/06/2013 12:00:00 PM', 103) 
INSERT INTO date (startdate) VALUES (@MyDate)
```

Very useful link to bookmark is found here related to this. http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Since the value is coming from the calling code (and isn't a fixed value in some static sql), IMO it would still be far better to parameterize the value in the first place, rather than concatenate it into a literal. Parameters are strongly-typed - no need for a potentially ambiguous format/parse step. It allows better query plan re-use, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can insert into database SQL Server using

insert into date (startdate) VALUES ('06/13/2013 12:00:00 PM')

the format for datetime is mm/dd/yy...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you putting into the sql query, then you can use below:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101)
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: There's a mistake: getdate?

Comment: getdate() returns the current date. He's trying to insert other data.