# Insert multiple datetime value in sql database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

There is this question here: [insert datetime value in sql database with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032495/insert-datetime-value-in-sql-database-with-c-sharp) that works perfectly but I want to do something like this:

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
     for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
     {
           commandText += string.Format( "insert into table (valuecoumn,datecolumn)" +
           "values({0},{1});" , 
           Request.Form["value-"+ i.ToString()],
           Request.Form["date-"+ i.ToString()]);

     }
     cmd.CommandText = commandText;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         
}
```

Now how should I deal with this as there are multiple date values?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part

Comment: @Tarik this is not what I'm looking for. I'm inserting using c#

Comment: @Rahul the code is the same for C# and asp.net C# thats why I hadn't added asp.net tag

Comment: You would be better off using a prepared parametrized query. You will avoid repeating the "insert into" and only the datetime value will be sent in binary format. In addition, the query is parsed only once by the RDBMS.

Comment: @Tarik I always use stored procedures. but was something quick and more important I wanted to know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting single-quotes around the date-value in your format string

```
    '{1}'
```

See if that helps. In fact there is actually no problem quoting up all your values that way. SQL Server will un-quote anything it doesn't like quoted.