# Take data from 3 different DropdownList's into an SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So I'm trying to create the following: I have 3 Dropdowns (one for the day, another for the month and other for the year) and I want to concatenate these three elements on the SQL Database.

Basically, it's a Birthday date I want to save.

**Pictures:**

[image: Where the user select the Birthday Date]

[image: Where I want to save the Date 'all together' (day, month and year)]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `string.Format` in c# before saving it to the database.

Comment: Check out this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032495/insert-datetime-value-in-sql-database-with-c-sharp

Comment: it didn't help me much.... I can't understand what is being done :\

Comment: If your database wants a DateTime (and I hope it does), simply use `var dateOfBirth = new DateTime(year, month, day);` and insert that into your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the date and using following snippet to store the value to database.

```
var date = new DateTime(year, month, date);


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO <table> (<column>) VALUES (@value)", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", date);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```