# Fill Datagrid with Sql Query using Date " 'Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int''

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, mdf

I am new to Programming and I started with C# (Visual Studio 2017 CE);
I am writing an application and using a `DataGrid`. I am trying to fill the `DataGrid` using a query to a C# service based DB (mdf file).
When I run the app and try the query statement I get this error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

at the `SqlDataReader` Line.
I have tested the SQL `Select` statement in the SQL Server and it works there. I have read multiple questions related to the error, but since I am a rookie to programming almost all answers are difficult to understand, Thanks in advance for your understanding

```
using (SqlConnection conn = Conexion.Conectado())
{
    string strsql = "SELECT dbo.Personas.Nombres, dbo.Personas.Apellidos, dbo.Prestamo.prestamo_id, dbo.Prestamo.fecha, dbo.Prestamo.Monto_prestamo, dbo.Prestamo.Ruta, dbo.Prestamo.Quotas, dbo.Prestamo.Balance, dbo.Registro_pagos.Monto_pago, dbo.Registro_pagos.Mora FROM dbo.Personas INNER JOIN dbo.Prestamo ON dbo.Personas.Persona_id = dbo.Prestamo.fk_Persona_id INNER JOIN dbo.Registro_pagos ON dbo.Prestamo.prestamo_id = dbo.Registro_pagos.fk_prestamo_id where dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha_pago = " + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text;


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string Nombres = dr["Nombres"].ToString();
        string Apellidos = dr["Apellidos"].ToString();
        string num_prestamo = dr["prestamo_id"].ToString();
        DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"].ToString());
        double Monto_prestamo = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Monto_prestamo"].ToString());
        string Codigo_ruta = dr["Ruta"].ToString();
        string Quotas = dr["Quotas"].ToString();
        double Balance = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Balance"].ToString());
        double Monto_pago = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Monto_pago"].ToString());
        double Mora = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Mora"].ToString());

        Dgv_cuadre_rutas.Rows.Add(Nombres, Apellidos, num_prestamo, fecha,Monto_prestamo , Codigo_ruta, Quotas, Balance, Monto_pago, Mora);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: @mjwills i formatted it but its  pending for peer review

Comment: Thanks for the help with my Question formatting!

Comment: @engel are you getting exception at this line ?  `DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"].ToString());` what is the datatype for `fecha` column in your table?

Comment: what value is dr["fecha"].ToString()) returning?

Comment: @Niladri the datatype is Date

Comment: Since I posted the question, I tried to find a solution, I tried you suggestion but the problem is generated by the sql query, I removed from the query everything after the "Where" and it works.  My problem is that I need the data that will be filled equal to the selected date from the datetimepicker, Still can't find the solution

Comment: What happens if you change `dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha_pago = " + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text;` to `dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha = '" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text; + "'"` or `dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha_pago = '" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text; + "'"`? What is the value of `Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032519/34092 shows you how to pass datetime as part of a query - you should use a parameterised query.

Comment: when use "dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha = '" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text; + "'" No error occurs but also no data is populated in the datagrid, the Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text value is a datetimepicker value (date)

Comment: Did you read the link I provide @engel ? You need to pass in parameters rather than concatenate strings.

Comment: I normally use  stackoverflow.com/a/1032519/34092 example when saving to DB, but not really sure how to use it to fill the datagrid based on the selected date, Please bear in mind I am a rookie and be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

Uses SQL DataAdapter instead which is much easier and will get rid of error

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = Conexion.Conectado())
            {
                string strsql = "SELECT dbo.Personas.Nombres, dbo.Personas.Apellidos, dbo.Prestamo.prestamo_id, dbo.Prestamo.fecha, dbo.Prestamo.Monto_prestamo, dbo.Prestamo.Ruta, dbo.Prestamo.Quotas, dbo.Prestamo.Balance, dbo.Registro_pagos.Monto_pago, dbo.Registro_pagos.Mora FROM dbo.Personas INNER JOIN dbo.Prestamo ON dbo.Personas.Persona_id = dbo.Prestamo.fk_Persona_id INNER JOIN dbo.Registro_pagos ON dbo.Prestamo.prestamo_id = dbo.Registro_pagos.fk_prestamo_id where dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha_pago = " + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text;


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, conn);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                Dgv_cuadre_rutas.DataSource = dt;

                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply,  the DataAdapter did not solve the issue,  I still get the same error at the adapter.fill(dt) line

Comment: There is something wrong with the database of your DGV.  Are you setting the properties of the DGV in your code?  I would delete the DGV from form and re-add and see if issue goes away.  I suspect you set one of the columns in the DGV as an integer and the DataBase has a Date in the column.

Comment: we had the same thought, I did remove my datagrid and place a new one without additional formation, but had the same error: then changed the select statement at the end of the line for this "like'" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text + "%'"; and the error disappeared but the datagrid is displaying only the DB colums headers with empty cells, before I did this changes I hace a datagrid with columns added, the code added more columns at the time

Comment: I would open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL server.  Then take your select query and run on SSMS to see if you have any results.  You  may need to add to your query "Use XXX" where XXX is the DataBase name.  or add to your connection string the default name of the DataBase.

Comment: Did as suggested, please see the print screen it returns all available data here a link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5E983k23FC6anhDcDZNb1cycVk

Comment: If you are getting columns and no rows in c# and getting rows in SSMS then you are either connecting to a different database or a difference Table in the database.  I do not recommend using the mdf file name in the connection string for c#.  Instead I recommend using the same connection as in SSMS login window and then using the database name in the SSMS explorer.

Comment: in this project I have two more datagrids one is filled when form loads and the other exact with same code posted here, but query uses a string character from text box instead of datetimepicker, both with formatted with columns datagrid. Again thanks for your time, if you come with any other idea I surely will appreciate it.

Comment: Textbox returns a string while a datetimepicker returns as DateTime.  For the two to be equivalent you need to take the DateTime object and use ToString("format").  It looks like the error is due to the SQL driver thinking the DateTime is an integer.  It is always advise to use Parameters with queries to prevent types from being converted incorrectly.  It is like iin Excel where General Formatting often will convert an integer to the Date or a Date to an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error! the error occurs first because in my original query I was using " = " + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Text;" the equal sends the data in an int format, so I had to change it to "--like '" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Value.ToString() +"'";,-- but at this point it was not filling up the datagrid, then I came up with the idea that, date string being send was not in the correct format, and adjusted the query to "like '" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"'"; and this solve my problem, thanks all that helped me here – engel 1 min ago   edit

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = Conexion.Conectado())
        {

            string strsql = "SELECT dbo.Personas.Nombres, dbo.Personas.Apellidos, dbo.Prestamo.prestamo_id, dbo.Prestamo.fecha, dbo.Prestamo.Monto_prestamo, dbo.Prestamo.Ruta, dbo.Prestamo.Quotas, dbo.Prestamo.Balance, dbo.Registro_pagos.Monto_pago, dbo.Registro_pagos.Mora FROM dbo.Personas INNER JOIN dbo.Prestamo ON dbo.Personas.Persona_id = dbo.Prestamo.fk_Persona_id INNER JOIN dbo.Registro_pagos ON dbo.Prestamo.prestamo_id = dbo.Registro_pagos.fk_prestamo_id where dbo.Registro_pagos.fecha_pago like '" + Dtp_fecha_cuadre.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"'";


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

                string Nombres = dr["Nombres"].ToString();
                string Apellidos = dr["Apellidos"].ToString();
                string num_prestamo = dr["prestamo_id"].ToString();
                DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"].ToString());
                double Monto_prestamo = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Monto_prestamo"].ToString());
                string Codigo_ruta = dr["Ruta"].ToString();
                string Quotas = dr["Quotas"].ToString();
                double Balance = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Balance"].ToString());
                double Monto_pago = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Monto_pago"].ToString());
                double Mora = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Mora"].ToString());


                Dgv_cuadre_rutas.Rows.Add(Nombres, Apellidos, num_prestamo, fecha, Monto_prestamo, Codigo_ruta, Quotas, Balance, Monto_pago, Mora);

            }
            conn.Close();
```